# ios/swift How to calculate label width before showing it

Tags: swift, uiview, label

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Label Text"
```

Get label width before addSubview.

view.addSubview(label)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function `width(forHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont)` for calculating string width.

```swift
let tetxWidth = "Label Text".width(forHeight: 15, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 14))
```

```swift
extension String {

    func width(forHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't always provide the correct value which result in text being clipped.